# adding a specific user link code to end of url

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url, hyperlink

I'm not quite sure how to explain this, but I need to be able to add a user's code to the end of the url of each page they go to.

Let me walk you through this.....I am a user, go to my site and type in my user code - which is NOT a login. There is no password, in theory there will be a box or some type of control that will allow a user to enter their code in.

This control will then add that user's code to the end of each URL for every page in the site and will also auto-populate all of the products in our database that are tied to that code.

The user is like a business or affiliate marketer. We need that code at the end of each URL that way when he sends his clients emails with links in them for purchasing, the client will click the link, and that marketer will get credit for the sale(s).

If this makes sense, will someone direct me to a helpful tutorial or explain how this works to me please? Thank you

I was told to use this code:

```
<ul id="p7menubar">
    <li><a href="<% =GetIB("http://products.pfgbest.com") %>">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="trigger">Lookup</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="<% =GetIB("Default.aspx") %>">Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="<% =GetIB("/FeatureSearch.aspx") %>">Feature</a></li>
        <li><a href="<% =GetIB("/DescriptionSearch.aspx") %>">Description</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li><!--end trigger li-->
    <div id="ib">
    Enter your IB code here:
        <asp:TextBox ID="IBTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="IBTextBoxButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    </div>
    </ul><!--end p7menubar-->


Partial Class MasterPage
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
Private _IB As String
Public Property IB() As String
    Get
        Return _IB
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _IB = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function GetIB(ByVal url As String) As String
    If (url.Contains("?")) Then
        Return "&IB=" & _IB
    Else
        Return url & "?IB=" & _IB
    End If
End Function

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("IB"))) Then
        _IB = Request.QueryString("IB")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

UPDATE: With the help of @DJ Quimby and ASP.net 3.5 for Dummies, I am now using this code and it seems to be taking it whatever value I type into my textbox:

```
 Protected Sub IBTextBoxButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles IBTextBoxButton.Click
    Session("IB") = IBTextBox.Text
    Dim IB As Integer = Session("IB")
    Response.Redirect("IBDefault.aspx?Baccount=" + Session("IB"))
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<a target="_blank" href="<%# eval("Data") %>?IB=(Session("IB"))"><%#Eval("Title")%></a>
```

The "IB" gets underlined and says it must be followed by an equal (=) sign and a value. Or if in quotation marks, they must match.

Comment: If you specify what sort of environment you are developing in, we'll be able to give you a more meaningful answer.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'm using ASP.net 4.0 VB

Comment: If you are just looking to persist data so that each page can use it, using 'Session' and 'SessionState' might make more sense for you.

Comment: @DJQuimby This part of my project was put on hold for a while, but I am back to it now. I checked out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx but it is a really old tutorial, do you know any places I can go to get the information I need that is current? I only seem to find old information that is pretty much worthless now.

Comment: Give this a shot: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: side note: if you're using VB.NET on the .NET 4 framework, you can use auto properties. `Public Property IB As String` is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there are any private data concerns, it may be best to store the user's code into session.

You can add most any variable you want to the session by doing the following:
    Session("userCode") = "12"

And retrieve it like this:
    'Dim userCode as Integer'
    'userCode = Session("userCode")'

Just make sure that the type you store it as is compatible with the type you assign it to when you pull it back down.

To check on each page you could declare a private variable within the page to store the value:
    `Private userCode As Integer`

And then
    `Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`
    `userCode = Session("userCode")`
    `End Sub`

Then just execute whatever other code you need to using that value.

Comment: So how can I make sure that every page that gets visited returns with the value that user entered in the textbox?

Comment: @jlg Edited my initial post to answer your question.

Comment: How do I put this code at the end of the URL? I added more to the original post, can't quite get it to work.

Comment: Now that you are using the session variable, you don't need to append the request string to the URL.  You can access the session variable from any page's code-behind as long as the user's session hasn't timed out.  I am less fluent with the inline asp that you posted, so if that's the route you plan to go down, you'll need to post a separate question to SO to get a better answer.  HTH

Comment: Oh I have to use that code at the end so that all a user has to do is copy and paste that code in emails to their clients to get credit on their sales. Thanks, I'll post somewhere else